# Free path length of microscopic black holes through degenerate matter

Tags: black-holes, neutron-stars

How would one approach calculating free path length of a microscopic black hole through degenerate matter? I wondered about how the interaction of a microscopic black hole with a neutron star would play out, depending on the mass, and therefore radius of the black hole and the mass, and thereby density of the neutron star.

I'm also wondering if there might be a long lived equilibrium of degenerate matter density and black hole radius, that would "stabilize" by gravitational pressure a lump of degenerate matter accumulated around the black hole; assuming that the free path length of the microscopic black hole through the degenerate matter is on the order of the size of the lump, so that the black hole can eat away on it only slowly.